# How do I deal with Error: numpy.float64 not iterable and KeyError: nan in Dict?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary, keyerror

I'm trying to create a new dictionary `dDrugs`  by extracting a list of `drugs` from `data`  dictionary (with bunch of string values) along with the key that's associated with the extracted drug (regardless of how many keys have the same drug as a value). My goal is to use the values from the `dDrugs` dictionary to create a new column in an existing pandas dataframe `dFrame`, using the keys to locate and populate the appropriate record in the dataframe. So far, here's what I've got:

```
data{
 530.0: 'AC FOLLOWED BY Tylenol',
 651.0: nan,
 692.0: nan,
 993.0: 'Penicillin 250mg',
 044.0: nan,
 055.0: 'septrim GIVEN 2x daily.',
 476.0: nan,
 817.0: 'penicilin 100MG & ibuprofen 1160MG',
 748.0: 'ADVIL;',
 258.0: 'Glaxo welc 50mg;',
 569.0: nan,
 140.0: 'dfafdg ghjgjkgk hgk',
 863.0: nan,
 504.0: 'Doxicycline',
 675.0: 'water'
 }

drugs = ['cycline', 'advil', 'penicilin', 'penicillin', 'tylenol', 'ibuprofen']

data =   dict([(k, val) for k, val in data.items() if(val)])#this was supposed to clean the dict
data = dict((k, v) for k, v in data.items() if v)#so is this but I still get KeyError nan
dDrugs = {}
for drugsuffix in drugs:
    drugre = re.compile(r'([A-Za-z][a-z]{4,}%s)[^a-z]'%(drugsuffix.lower(),))
    for key, value in data.items():
        for chtxt in data[value]:
            for m in drugre.finditer(chtxt+" "):
                drugname = m.group(1)
                dDrugs[key].append(drugname.lower())

#been stuck here like forever!                

#Error
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-118-0a4cff097dc9> in <module>()
      7     drugre = re.compile(r'([A-Za-z][a-z]{4,}%s)[^a-z]'%
(drugsuffix.lower(),))
      8     for key, value in data.items():
----> 9         for chtxt in data[value]:
     10             for m in drugre.finditer(chtxt+" "):
     11                 drugname = m.group(1)

KeyError: nan
```

What do I do to fix this? and Achieve my ultimate goal? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dictionary isn't getting cleaned because `np.nan` doesn't behave like `None`. Specifically,

```
>>>bool(np.nan)
True
```

However,

```
>>>np.nan == np.nan
False
```

So

```
{k: v for k, v in data.items() if v == v}
```

will actually clean your dictionary.

For your problem, replacing your nested loops with

```
for k, v in data.items():
    dDrugs[k] = [drug for drug in drugs if drug in v.lower()]
```

seems to work.

For adding the column, you should just be able to use `.map(dDrugs)` on whatever column contains the keys.

**Edit:**
To pull the full name on a partial match, you can use the `findall` method of a regex based on the drug:

```
drugs = [re.compile('\S*'+drug) for drug in drugs]
for k, v in data.items():
    dDrugs[k] = [drug for drug_suffix in drugs
                 for drug in drug_suffix.findall(v.lower())]
dDrugs
Out[1482]: 
{55.0: [],
 140.0: [],
 258.0: [],
 504.0: ['doxicycline'],
 530.0: ['tylenol'],
 675.0: [],
 748.0: ['advil'],
 817.0: ['penicilin', 'ibuprofen'],
 993.0: ['penicillin']}
```

`findall` returns a list, which necessitates the double comprehension. The regex I used here just takes all non-whitespace characters, if any, before the given suffix going back to the last whitespace character, if any. For your full dataset you may want something more complex.

Comment: This is certainly the fastest solution I've recieved on this platform. Thank you so much. I give a feedback as so as I test this out.

Comment: Hello EFT, the nested loop replacement you provided works like magic and it made my code run faster...Thank you!!!

Comment: The only problem is that it works perfectly for drugs that has their full name spelled out. For instance, there are so many drugs with the suffix 'cycline' such as doxicycline, tetracycline, etc. So instead of listing all the cycline drugs, I listed cycline in my drug list with the expectation that the code would pull out a drug with such suffix. I've been trying to see how I could tweak your loop to produce such output but haven't been successful. Could you please take a look? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you ETF! The Regex actually worked with my dataset. Only problem is it doesn't separate hyphenated or / texts (i.e. 03/14/05-doxicycline and ibruprofen/penicilin). Though I'm working on the search pattern to improve on that (maybe even extract the dates completely), please let me know if you've got more thoughts. Thank you once again.